# Proportionality of distance to work in differing conditions

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, gravity, work, potential-energy

Why is Work done by $F_{grav}$ and EMF proportional to distance but work done by $F_{elastic}$ proportional to the square of the distance?

Comment: Work is the path integral of the dot product of the force vector with incremental displacement.  For constant force in the same direction as a linear displacement, work is force times distance.  For non-constant forces (like $F_{elastic}$) you have to do the integral.